# Github adding multiple accounts to same machine along with different usernames/ email with different Account commits

Tags: git, github, user-accounts

I have two github accounts which i am using on same computer.
I have been successful in connecting and commiting the changes to both of my github accounts from same machine.

The issue I am facing is I am not sure the commits that are being done - how to automatically set different usernames email value to different Host names or github accounts

My new config file looks like -

```
#Default GitHub
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host github-COMPANY
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_COMPANY
```

If my try to commit to any public repo of my company it takes my personal github name configuration which I initially set up in global config file..

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Kaushik

Comment: Try changing the name of the first `Host` line to something like `github-personal`, so that the `HostName` of the second entry doesn't match the `Host` line of the first entry.

Comment: @merlin2011 : how will that help, I am not sure. What I need is when i am using the second HOST as github-company, it should automatically take a different name and email than what is set as in global config settings

Answer (score 1):

> how to automatically set different usernames email value to different Host names or github accounts

This isn't  related to your ssh private key IdentityFile that you would use to authenticate yourself to GitHub when pushing a repo.

Commits are done independently of any https or (in your case) ssh credentials.
Their committer / author names and emails depends on the global or local config user.name and user.email.

In each of your repo, type

```
git config user.name  theRightName
git config user.email theRight@email
```

And you will have the correct values for those repos.

Comment: Does that mean , every time I switch the accounts on my same machine , I need to set the user name and email to my config file??

Comment: @KaushikRay no, the account you mention in your question are for authentication to the remote Git repo hosting server (GitHub). the `user.name` and `user.email` I mention is set repo per repo or globally (`git config --global`) and is for author and comitter of each commit.

Comment: @KaushikRay A nice article, also it explains setting alias http://www.codeography.com/2011/08/05/project-specific-git-author.html